# JSTL c:set wrapped around custom JSP tag for ATG Repository lookup

Tags: jsp, jstl

Sorry for the verbose title, but it's a verbose problem. I am trying to interface with a CMS of sorts, but the HTML produced by my custom tag is getting output to the page in addition to being saved in a JSTL variable. I don't even know if what I'm trying to achieve is possible.

```
<%-- promo.tag --%>
<%@ tag display-name="PromoMap Lookup Tag" body-content="empty" %>
<%@ attribute name="id" required="true" description="" %>
<%@ attribute name="elName" required="true" description="" %>

<%@ taglib uri="/dspTaglib" prefix="dsp" %>
<%@ taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core"      prefix="c" %>
<%@ taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/functions" prefix="fn" %>

<dsp:importbean bean="/promo/PromoMapLookup"/>

<dsp:droplet name="PromoMapLookup">
    <dsp:param name="id" value="${id}"/>
    <dsp:param name="elementName" value="${elName}"/>
    <dsp:oparam name="output">
        <c:set var="html"><dsp:valueof param="promo.html" valueishtml="true"/></c:set>
        <c:set var="html" value="${fn:trim(html)}"/>
        <c:if test="${not fn:endsWith(html, '-->') and not empty html}">
            ${html}
        </c:if>
    </dsp:oparam>
    <dsp:oparam name="empty">
        <%-- Nothing retrieved for promo slot id --%>
    </dsp:oparam>
</dsp:droplet>
```

...and then the calling page makes a call like this above all the html:

```
<%@ taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" prefix="c" %>
<%@ taglib tagdir="/WEB-INF/tags" prefix="pro" %>
<c:set var="masthead"><pro:promo id="287" elName="promo" /></c:set>

...some html...

${masthead}
```

The `elName` attribute is internal, so don't worry about that. So, the html that `PromoMapLookup` spits out IS getting saved to the variable, but it gets rendered on the page where the `c:set` tag is being called, in addition to where I reference the variable later in the page. The result is the same html in two places on the page. I have a feeling this has something to do with the order of compiling/rendering, but I can't figure it out. Any ideas?

Comment: What are you trying to do?  Is `promo.html` the name of a file or the name of an output variable set in PromoMapLookup?  The problem is that you want to just save it to a variable instead of display it twice?  Also, I'm not seeing the connection between the two code snippets.  What does your tld look like?

Answer (score 0):

So I ended up solving this issue. The problem was that I was using the `<dsp:valueof>` tag to retrieve the promo.html (promo is a reference to table with the field "html"). Once I changed the tag to `<dsp:getvalueof param="promo.html" var="html"/>` and removed the surrounding `<c:set>` tags, it all worked out.

The getvalueof DSP tag allows the value to be stored into a JSTL variable directly, while the valueof tag outputs the value in place (even though it was also captured into the JSTL variable via the `<c:set>` tags.